# Multiple Classes inside my library: incomplete type is not allowed

Tags: c++, object, instantiation

This is the first time that I am splitting my library functionality into multiple classes.  I am not exactly sure how to instantiate my objects per the classes.  Am I required to instantiate the class objects in order to access those class methods and variables even though the classes are in the same .h file? I am receiving the error 'incomplete type is not allowed' for line 30.

My code:

```
/*
File: sensor.h

Header file for phSensor Library.
*/

#ifndef SENSOR_H
#define SENSOR_H

#include "mbed.h"
#include "cfExtensions.h"
#include "msExtensions.h"

#include <string>

class phSensor;
class ecSensor;
class tempSensor;

class sensor
{
public:
    sensor(); //Default sensor constructor
    sensor(cfExtensions &cfExt, msExtensions &msExt);

private:
    cfExtensions &_cfExt;
    msExtensions &_msExt;

    phSensor     ph;  // Line 30, gets error "incomplete type is not allowed"
    ecSensor     ec;
    tempSensor   temp;

    string _phCurrentPhValue;
    string _phMaxValue;
    string _phMinValue;

};

class phSensor
    : public sensor
{
public:
    phSensor();

    void outputPhMaxValue();

private:
    float _getCurrentPhValue();
    float _getPhMaxValue();
    float _getPhMinValue();

    void _setPhMaxValue();
    void _setPhMinValue();

    void _calibratePhSensor();

    Ticker getPhMax;
    Ticker getPhMin;
};

class ecSensor
    : public sensor
{
public:
    ecSensor();
};

class tempSensor
    : public sensor
{
public:
    tempSensor();

};

#endif
```

Comment: Could you show the line itself that gives the error, so we don't have to try to count the lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have already commented about the problem with the declaration `phSensor ph;`.

I'm going to comment about your design.

**About your `class sensor`**
First off, why are you doing this?

One of the first things you learn in object oriented is about inheritance, for example a `Vehicle` class, with `Car`, `Truck`, and `Bicycle` all being subclasses of that base vehicle class. Very nice, very simple, but often wrong. Eventually you need to unlearn that naive view of object oriented programming.

Case in point: Just because pH sensors, electrical conductivity sensors, and temperature sensors are all sensors of some type does not necessarily mean that it is a good idea to make a `Sensor` base class. What are the common elements shared by all sensors? If there are none, perhaps it's not such a good idea to have that `sensor` base class.

**Do one thing and do it well**
Your `sensor` class is doing two things. It is serving as a base class for those other sensor classes *and* it is serving as a collection of three kinds of sensors. These are two very different things, so these different behaviors should be in two very different classes. Your immediate problems would go away if you split that class into two classes, `sensor` to act as the base class (if needed; see above) and a `multisensor` that contains a pH sensor, an electrical conductivity sensor, and a temperature sensor. There's no need to make this `multisensor` class inherit from `sensor`, or even from `phsensor` etc. This new class would instead contain multiple sensors. Composition is oftentimes a much better route than inheritance.

**About the class `sensor` constructors**
You have two data members that are references. References can only be set by a constructor, and only in the initializer list. I can see what the non-default constructor does. What does your default constructor do? Your derived classes only have default constructors, which suggests that they are calling the `sensor` class's default constructor. Does this make sense? It might be better to get rid of those default constructors. The standard way to do this in C++03 is to declare the default constructor private but never provide an implementation. There's a better option in C++11, which is to declare the constructor as deleted.

Comment: Well said.  The whole purpose of the sensor class was to call the other sensor methods and get variable values. This is a huge learning experience for me.  I now separated the ph, ec and temp into their own libraries.  The separate sensor libraries will contain their own variables, getter, setter methods and etc.  I was thinking of still incorporating the sensor library to execute the ph, ec and temp library methods. Is that considered an efficient code pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare only pointers or references to incomplete types, in your case

```
phSensor     ph;
ecSensor     ec;
tempSensor   temp;
```

all these will give an error, the layout of the `sensor` cannot be defined without knowing the layout of all the members.

Also, it's not possible for an object to contain a subobject of its own class, but that's what you're trying to do - `phSensor` and `ecSensor` both inherit `sensor` and are members of `sensor`. Most probably you need these to be pointers.

```
phSensor     *ph;
ecSensor     *ec;
tempSensor   *temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You declare the phSensor-class, so the type name is known. Still, at this point the compiler knows nothing about the members or methods of that class, so it can not know the size of the type. As long as the class was only declared and not defined, you can only use pointers or references with it.

Also: If you look closely at your class layout, this cannot work.
Lets say you instantiate phSensor. phSensor extends sensor, so all members of sensor are initialized as well. One of these members is a phSensor again, which is derived from sensor, which holds another phSensor inheriting sensor and so on. You see, this instantiation would never end and use up all memory.

Answer (score 1):

You should't declare the classes in the same file. The idea of modularize the code haven't sense if you do that.